# How to give priority to a div in terms of overlapping divs on a drop down menu?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I added a new navigation menu to my website. It's one I found from a tutorial and I am having an issue with it. It appears to be hiding behind the div directly below it. I have tried z index but that does not work in this case. I am using z index though. I have the div above the nav menu fixed so that it moves with the page when I scroll.

This fiddle is of most of the site. there is a lot of code but I do not know where the issue is so I added most of it. The last bit of css is for the datatables.

The following code is the div containing the nav menu (not sure if that's relevant.)

```
.box{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:1000px;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:220px;
    z-index:1;

}
```

So basically how can I make it so that the nav menu does not hide behind the bottom div. the content which is the datatables.

As always thanks in advance!

EDIT: I removed overflow:hidden from the .box and now it shows me the menu but it pushes all the divs and content below it down when the menu drops down. Anyway to fix this?

Comment: Its hidden because of overflow:hidden. The wierd thing is that absolute moves an element outside of the normal flow of the DOM. So thats your true issue.

Comment: EDIT: one sec let me change it.

Comment: To class .box. But fixing the problem should go away with position abslolute. Thats where im looking.

Comment: Ok I removed overflow:hidden from .box (the container div for the menu). After doing so It allows me to see the menu but It also makes a scroll box appear so I have to scroll to see it. How can I fix that? jsfiddle updated.

Comment: Remove position: absolute; from class .ldd_submenu

Comment: Alright were getting closer. That worked. However when the drop down menu drops down it pushes all the divs and content below it down as well. Anyway to fix that? Thanks.

Comment: It doesnt fix your problem though, imo here is how you can do it. Position:absolute your content class, and do a 20em top, then reduce its z-index to 0, and increase your z-index to 999 on your box class. That will do it.

Comment: What do you mean by 20em top? Whats the tag/element/code for it? I' new to all this and barly following you. sorry.

Comment: What about setting the z-index of the .ldd_submenu class while keeping it positioned absolutely? I can't see if this is working in jsfiddle.

Comment: Yeah I tried that and it didn't work Cam. Polly I will try that now

Comment: @PollyShaw that was my first thought, but there is a external script applying a overflow: hidden to each span.

Comment: @user2106354 did you see my jsfiddle??

Comment: @polly that did not work either. It just puts it back in a scroll box.

Comment: @Cam i do not see your jsfiddle. Where is it?

Comment: In the answer I provided at the bottom. http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/eNp8F/16/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your solution. Adjust to whatever you need it to be.
http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/eNp8F/16/

```
.box{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:1000px;
position:relative;
margin-top:220px;
z-index:999;
height: 400px;
```

}

```
#content {
/* Background color, gradients & Rounded Corners */

background-color: #121212;
border: 1px solid #343434;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px ;
-webkit-box-shadow:  1px 4px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 9);
box-shadow:  1px 4px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 9);

-webkit-box-shadow:  1px 4px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 9);
box-shadow:  1px 4px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 9);

margin:20px;
padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
position: absolute;
top: 20em;
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This ALMOST works. Cosmetically it has positioned everything correctly. But now half of the datatable (whats in the content div) is not clickable and my mouse over effects are not working. Theres still something overlapping. You just cant see it. IE: when i hover over the very first row in the table the header should change. but it only works on links farther down the list. Like something is over top of them half way down. and if you look at the jsfidle the first link isnt clickable.

Comment: It has to do with the height of the .box

Comment: ya, delete height:400px, it should just be auto. I think that will fix it.

Comment: Ok, my solution isnt working.. Back to the drawing board

Comment: Hey I got it to work using your solution and a minor change. Your solution answered the question I had asked tho so I'm going to accept it thank you.